# Android: catching action for keyboard enter button being pressed

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I am trying to respond to pressing the enter button on a standard system on screen soft keybord, in numeric mode. keyboard appears on the screen when myCustomEditText class is given focus.

tried 2 approaches:

1. overriding `onKeyDown()`:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            //do sth..
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

1. setting listener `setOnKeyListener`:

```
    myCustomEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                onRightButtonClicked();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

(also tried `onKeyDown()` in myCustomEditText as well, but with no effect)

**problem is:**
these aproaches above works for all the keys being pressed but for the **enter** key - the methods are not even being fired at all. (it's not a problem of bad `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_...`)

**my question is:**
why these methods are not being fired for enter key, but are for other keys, and how to listen to enter key being pressed properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You respond to <kbd>ENTER</kbd> differently than normal keys, try something like this:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (actionId) {

            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                ...
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

You can specify which action is performed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> by specifiying `android:imeOptions` in XML or by calling `editText.setImeOptions(...)` with one of the constants in `EditorInfo`. `imeOptions` also changes how the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key looks! For example if you set `imeOptions` to `actionSearch` then the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key will look like a search button.

You can find a list of all possible values for `imeOptions` along with a description [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions).

Comment: Do you have an idea how to set TextView.OnEditorActionListener() on EditText class object? I am getting "setOnEditorActionListener is undefined for myCustomEditText" error

Comment: Well if you get that error than you are not using an `EditText`. What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Nevermind, it should work on EditText as well, but i was tring to set the listener on sth else ;) Thanks!

Comment: I had to also respond to IME_NULL