# Edit text will not post KEYCODE_ENTER to keylistener after setting the digits tag

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text that I taking only digits and decimals. I want it to also take fractions, and I have gotten this to work. The problem is after setting the digits tag in xml to "0123456789./ " it will no longer post the KEYCODE_ENTER to the listener when the enter button is pressed. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
     android:digits="1234567890./ "
     android:id="@+id/itsname"
     android:ems="@integer/itslength"
     android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why they did it this way but you can work around the problem by setting the imeOptions tag in the xml and then adding a OnEditorActionListener to the EditText.

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener enterListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (actionId) {

            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                Log.e("Listen","TO IT ALL");
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
};
```

XML:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Credit goes to this guy for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25136275/4491275